# How to iterate through classes in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

The problem is all the cards are the same color, what I would like is for each card to be given one of five colors at random when the page loads.

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    oneToFive = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    switch (oneToFive) {
        case 1:
            randColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)";
            break;
        case 2:
            randColor = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.25)";
            break;
        case 3:
            randColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)";
            break;
        case 4:
            randColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)";
            break;
        case 5:
            randColor = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25)";
            break;
        default:
            randColor = "rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.25)";
            break;
    }

    $(".card-color").each(function(){
        $(".card-color").css("background-color", randColor);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue with your logic is that you only generate `randColor` once when the pages loads. To make it work as you require you need to generate the random colour inside the `each()` handler. You also need to use the `this` keyword to reference only the current element within that handler.

You can also make the code more succinct by using an array instead of the `switch`. Try this:

```js
var colours = ['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)', 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.25)', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25)', 'rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.25)'];

$(".card-color").each(function() {
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  $(this).css("background-color", colours[rnd]);
});
```

```css
.card-color {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-color"></div>
<div class="card-color"></div>
<div class="card-color"></div>
<div class="card-color"></div>
<div class="card-color"></div>
<div class="card-color"></div>
<div class="card-color"></div>
<div class="card-color"></div>
<div class="card-color"></div>
<div class="card-color"></div>
```

Comment: I always miss the silliest things. I have updated it on the live version and it looks good, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of issues:

1. You need to call the random function each time you want a colour, not just once otherwise it will always be the same value
2. You need to set css on the individual element, not all elements that match the class. In an `each` function you can access this specific element using `this`

Here is a full example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".card-color").each(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", getRandomColor());
    });
});

function getRandomColor(){
    var randColor = '';
    var oneToFive = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
    switch (oneToFive) {
        case 1:
            randColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25)";
            break;
        case 2:
            randColor = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.25)";
            break;
        case 3:
            randColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)";
            break;
        case 4:
            randColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)";
            break;
        case 5:
            randColor = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25)";
            break;
        default:
            randColor = "rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.25)";
            break;
    }
    return randColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your switch statement inside each function. So it will always get new color.

Answer (score 0):

try this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ntq7xLLq/1/)

```
var all = $(".card-color").map(function() {
oneToFive = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
switch (oneToFive) {
    case 1:
        randColor = 'red';
        break;
    case 2:
        randColor = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.25)";
        break;
    case 3:
        randColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)";
        break;
    case 4:
        randColor = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)";
        break;
    case 5:
        randColor = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25)";
        break;
    default:
        randColor = "rgba(122, 122, 122, 0.25)";
        break;
}
 $(this).css('background-color', randColor);
}).get()
```